# How to handle python TypeError NoneType object is not subscriptable on dict value to continue executing

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests

I am doing GET operations against Netbox API for collecting data. I am trying to figure out how
to handle this error so my script continues to run and finishes collecting all the sites data:

```
\Documents\Netbox\netbox_api.py", line 179, in <module>
    region_name = site['region']['name']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This error stalls it and does not complete the __ getitem __() indexing for all the sites because not all `sites_response =requests.request("GET", url_dcim_sites, headers=headers, data=payload)`
contain "valid" data for Region key, I think. So it stops after this last item: `| Region: CE         | Status: active` , because the next site has None for Region value.

Code:

```
sites_response =requests.request("GET", url_dcim_sites, headers=headers, data=payload)

sites_json = sites_response.json()

sites_results = sites_json['results']

for site in sites_results:
  id_number = site['id']
  name = site['name']
  region_name = site['region']['name']
  status = site['status']['value']
  #print(f"ID:{id_number:5} | Hostname:{hostname:20} | IP Address:{ipaddr!s:12} | Site:{site_id:5}") 
  sites = dict(ID=id_number, Name=name, Region=region_name, Status=status)
  format_sites = f"ID: {sites['ID']:5} | Name: {sites['Name']:20} | Region: {sites['Region']:10} | Status: {sites['Status']:5}"
  print(format_sites)
```

Unsure how to approach handling the `region_name` line so that any Site that has None for `['name']` does not get subscripted, and I can avoid the TypeError. Can I just check if the object value has NoneType and then ignore it? It works for the first 30 or so Sites before it encounters the error because all the Sites prior contain a name value for Region.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [get function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) of a dictionary:

```
region_name = site.get("region", {}).get("name")
...
format_sites = f"ID: {sites.get("ID"):5} | Name: {sites.get("Name"):20} # ... and so on
```

this way no key error will raised even if the key "region" does not exist because the default value for it is an empty dictionary thus preventing an attribute error caused by the second get

Comment: I tried this at the top of the for loop:  `if site['region']['name'] is None:
    continue`. But I still get the error. I also tried your solution but I still get the same error. I think I should put the empty dict `{}` in the "name" since that is what is causing the TypeError, no? Region will awlays exist, it is the Name that can be None in the netbox api.

Comment: I tried the empty dict in the second get("name"), but I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. Same result when doing it within the first get method too. I think I am trying to avoid a ValueError.

Comment: I tested it in python 3.11 what version are you using?

Comment: 3.9.6. Should I update and retest?

Comment: @humbleStrength no need, i just tested it on python 3.9.6 and it still worked. I found the issue, you need to use the same get method in your f string. It is always good practice to use get instead of indexing, unless you want your code to throw an error

Comment: Thanks for your guidance so far. However, I am still getting the Attribute error for NoneType after making my format_sites like so:  `format_sites = f"ID: {sites.get('ID'):5} | Name: {sites.get('Name'):20} | Region: {sites.get('Region', {}):10} | Status: {sites.get('Status'):5}"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to proceed past the error by removing the dict value direct access or dict get method, whichever. Although, my data for that Region key is now a dictionary as a value, it is at least returning the default None if there is no string value for Region, per @Pear implementation. Not able to figure out how to just extract the key 'name' value from the nested dict, but that is minor. I also had to use a format conversion flag for getting the type to render correctly in my f string.

```
for site in sites_results:
  if site.values() is None:
    continue
  # region_name = site['region']['name']
  region_name = site.get("region", {})
  id_number = site['id']
  name = site['name']
  status = site['status']['value']
  #print(f"ID:{id_number:5} | Hostname:{hostname:20} | IP Address:{ipaddr!s:12} | Site:{site_id:5}") 
  sites = dict(ID=id_number, Name=name, Region=region_name, Status=status)
  # format_sites = f"ID: {sites['ID']:5} | Name: {sites['Name']:20} | Region: {sites['Region']:10} | Status: {sites['Status']:5}"
  format_sites2 = f"ID: {sites.get('ID'):5} | Name: {sites.get('Name'):20} | Region: {sites.get('Region', {})!s:10} | Status: {sites.get('Status'):5}"
  print(format_sites2)
```

Output

```
ID:  3498 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: None       | Status: active
ID:  3600 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: None       | Status: planned
ID:  3599 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: None       | Status: planned
ID:     3 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
ID:  3508 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
ID:  3523 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
ID:  3502 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: None       | Status: active
ID:     2 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
ID:  3652 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
ID:  3653 | Name: OBFUSCATED | Region: {'id': 14, 'url': 'OBFUSCATED', 'display': 'CE', 'name': 'CE', 'slug': 'ce', '_depth': 0} | Status: active
```